# GL_LINEAR / GL_NEAREST equivalent in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, opengl, directx-11, opengl-4

I have a scene in which i load the same texture only depending on its resolution i use different filtering modes in OpenGL, these are `GL_LINEAR`, `GL_NEAREST` and so on. For example, for a texture with a resolution below 128 pixels, I set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR`, and for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` I set `GL_NEAREST`. And if the texture resolution is more than 128 pixels, then I set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` and for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR`. In general, **I have a question what is the equivalent in DirectX 11 for this**, because otherwise I have a texture that has a resolution of less than 128 pixels to become blurry.

OpenGL: [image: OpenGL]

DirectX 11:[image]

This is how it looks in my code, only this is an example for both APIs.

```
if (width > 128 || height > 128) {
    min = TextureFilteringMode::LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR;
    mag = TextureFilteringMode::LINEAR;
} else if (width <= 128 || height <= 128) {
    min = TextureFilteringMode::LINEAR;
    mag = TextureFilteringMode::NEAREST;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all of the filtering options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_filter).
Your code if you had written it only for DirectX API would look something like this:

```
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampler_desc{};
if (width > 128 || height > 128) {
    sampler_desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    sampler_desc.MinLOD = 0;
    sampler_desc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX; //use all the mipmaps
} else if (width <= 128 || height <= 128) {
    sampler_desc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_LINEAR_MAG_MIP_POINT;
    sampler_desc.MinLOD = sampler_desc.MaxLOD = 0;
}
//fill the rest of desc
```

Since `GL_LINEAR/GL_NEAREST` for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` don't use mipmaps and all of the DirectX filtering options use mipmaps, you need to combine the filter option with `MinLOD/MaxLOD` parameters in `D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC` (which is also where the filter parameter is located). You set them both to `0` to force using only the most detail mip level.

Comment: Thanks! This perfectly works for me.